# Where is Rathwald?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I want to do the "Fall of Moria" instance. It is given by Rathwald near the gates of the Walls of Moria before I complete 2.1.8, and in the 21st Hall after. I cannot find Rathwald in the 21st hall, where is he?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't talk to Rathwald during the Moria intro, then you'll need to talk to him at the north-gate of the 21st hall *after* you reach level 50.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the Fall of Moria quest after entering Moria, find [Skygni](http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Skygni). He is in 21st Hall, just through the gates west of the stable-master. The link provide gives his exact coordinates.

Comment: Skygni has no quest for me. Why?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. If you want to try talking Ráthwald, [this link should help](http://lotro.mmodb.com/bestiary/r%C3%A1thwald-4754.php).